# google search result to my site takes me to a wrong url

Tags: url, redirect

I am a web developer and one of our client's site is having an issue which i am unable to figure out, url to the site is "www.theleatherdoc.com" when you search for "leather repair sandy Utah" it comes in first 3 results of google but it redirects you to some wrong or advertising url when you click on the search result, but directly you can access that site, any suggestions or ideas what problem might  is

Thank you

Comment: This question is not related to programming, but still I tried what you wrote, and I am really surprised.

Comment: Yes I know it's not related to programming, but I thought if someone has faced similar problem before, then it will be easier for me to figure out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have search at Google-US and found that your problem,I have analysis the whole problem from the root and found that the result which shows are in search engine are in the form of "Google listing results"

So in my opinion please re check your Google listing settings and verify your actual Link there.

I am sure your problem will be solve from there.